# AutocompleteSelect broken after moving from django 2.2 to django 3.2

Tags: django, django-widget

Hello :) After upgrading `Django` version to `3.2`, widget `AutocompleteSelect` that I use in `django` admin panel (to have a drop-down from which I can choose an object) **is broken**.

The error I see is

```
AttributeError at /admin/question/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/question/
Django Version: 3.2.13
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'
Exception Location: /home/django-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py, line 412, in build_attrs
Python Executable:  /home/django-app/env/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path:    
['/home/django-app/testsite',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/django-app/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 20 May 2022 10:13:27 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template /home/django-app/testsite/polls/templates/admin/question_export.html, error at line 18

'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'
11  
12  {% block content %}
13      <div id="content-main">
14        <p>Select question to export:</p>
15          <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
16              {% csrf_token %}
17              <table>
18                  {{form.as_table}}
19              </table>
20              <div class="submit-row">
21                  <input type="submit" value="Export Question" />
22              </div>
23          </form>
24      </div>
25      {{form.media}}
26  {% endblock %}
27
```

`AutocompleteSelect` inherits from `AutocompleteMixin`

When I compare `AutocompleteMixin` for `django 3.2` and `django 2.2`
https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.2.13/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L410-L412
https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.7/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L411

I see that they added new attributes

```
'data-app-label': self.field.model._meta.app_label,
'data-model-name': self.field.model._meta.model_name,
'data-field-name': self.field.name,
```

in `django 3.2`
but there is no `name` on `self.field` and probably that's why I get this error.

The code looks like this

view.py

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AutocompleteSelect

class QuestionChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    widget = AutocompleteSelect(Question.objects.all(), admin.site)


class QuestionExportForm(forms.Form):
    question = QuestionChoiceField(queryset=Question.objects.all(), required=True)

    def clean_question(self):
        return self.cleaned_data["question"]


class QuestionExportView(FormView):
    template_name = "admin/question_export.html"
    form_class = QuestionExportForm
    success_url = "/admin/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        question = form.cleaned_data.get("question")
        return generate_response(question)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

templates/admin/question_export.html

```
{% block content %}
    <div id="content-main">
      <p>Select question to export:</p>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                {{form.as_table}}
            </table>
            <div class="submit-row">
                <input type="submit" value="Export Question" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    {{form.media}}
{% endblock %}
```

How can I approach this issue? Any help would be appreciated :)!